# No indication of menu

Tags: menus, dropdown

I imported a menu from my bootstrap to wordpress theme, at time of just static html, it showed and worked fine but when i used the wp_nav_menu, i don't have a 'text' or any indication to dropdown that menu, as its a dropdown menu. Am i missing something in the following code?

```
   wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'              => 'primary',
        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
        'depth'             => 3,
        'container'         => 'div',
        'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
        'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
        'menu_class'        => ' dropdown-menu',
      )
    );
```

as i would like to have a arrow to click to open dropdown.

Edit: I tried walker class, but i don't get a indicator of my dropdown and my styles in css just fails and i think walker class just overwrite it.

Comment: You need to define a custom menu walker. There are some of them already made for Bootstrap and freely available in Github, for example [this one](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker).

Comment: @cybmeta yes i tried that. I edited the question to mention that. It completely break my layout like no more css works which i created and menu is opened, even if i do css to hidden until hover, it won't show a indicator which says menu to hover over to see dropdown.

Comment: I don't know if the linked walker class is correctly coded, if it is correct for your Bootstrap version or if it conflicts with your CSS/HTML, it was just an example of what you have to do: define a custom walker menu class that fit your needs. There are other walket classes for bootstrap in Github, just search that site to see examples, there are lots of them.

Comment: @cybmeta In view source, i cannot find wp_bootstrap_navwalker as its functions.php , should i be looking for something else, to find if it's included or not.

Comment: @cybmeta for some odd reason, when i created a secondary menu and assigned it some pages. The menu which had walker class, showed up with proper css. That is certainly strange. I wonder what happened.

Comment: @cybmeta walker class is great, but one problem. It is not showing my dropdown e.g 3 level and neither documentation say anything about it.

Comment: I'm going to repeat myself: use a custom menu walker class that fit your needs. If you don't find one already made, make it yourself. I don't know what more to say. If you need help of how to create and use a custom menu walker class, explain where do you have the problem with it. [This question and answer may help you to learn about extending menu walker class](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52323/wordpress-menu-custom-walker-class).